# Open file name passed from commandline argument that is in different location in the server

Tags: c++, linux, file-io, arguments, fopen

I want to open the filename name that I sent from command line but the file is in /home/docs/cs230 . Below is the code I tried but it shows error when I tried to compile in linux:

```
int main(int arg, char* args[1]) {
   // Open the file 
   newfile = fopen("/home/docs/cs230/"+args[1], "w+b");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this is C++ we can use `std::string` like so:

```
int main(int arg, char* args[]) {
   // Open the file 
   std::string path( "/home/docs/cs230/" ) ;

   path+= args[1] ;

   std::cout << path << std::endl ;

   FILE *newfile = fopen( path.c_str(), "w+b");
}
```

Mats also makes a great comment that in C++ we would use [fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/), which you can read more about at the link.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is C++, I would suggest this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])    
// Please don't make up your own names for argc/argv, it just confuses people!
{
    std::string filename = "/home/docs/cs230/";
    filename += argv[1]; 
    newfile = fopen(filename.c_str(), "w+b");
}
```

[Although to make it fully C++, you should use `fstream`, not a FILE

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with pointers you can concat the string (char*)

```
const char* path = "/home/docs/cs230/";
int size1 = sizeof(argv[1]);
int size2 = sizeof(path);
const char* result = new char[size1 + size2 + 2];
result[size1 + size2 + 1] = '\0';
memcpy( result, path, size1 );
memcpy( &result[ size1 ], argv[1], size2 );
```

not a recommended option, but there are a bunch of possibilities here.